# Replace an object which is inside an array ,and belongs to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which has objects inside it in a sub array called cartQuantityAllots. My intention is to replace the object by an updated object

```
const arr=[
    {
        "code": "756WP",
        "id": "full",
        "name": "Full Cart",
        "boxId": "box6",
        "cartQuantityAllots": [
            {
                "code": "A2001",
                "cartType": "halfCart",
                "typesOfItems": [
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Crockery - Tea Coffee Cups",
                        "value": "Crockery - Tea Coffee Cups",
                        "label": "Crockery - Tea Coffee Cups"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "SMU-Tea",
                        "value": "SMU-Tea",
                        "label": "SMU-Tea"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "All purpose glass",
                        "value": "All purpose glass",
                        "label": "All purpose glass"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "index": "Galley1",
        "imageGalley": "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png"
    },
    {
        "code": "756WP",
        "id": "full",
        "name": "Full Cart",
        "boxId": "box7",
        "cartQuantityAllots": [
            {
                "code": "A2002",
                "cartType": "halfCart",
                "typesOfItems": [
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks",
                        "value": "Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks",
                        "label": "Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Juices & sof Drinks",
                        "value": "Juices & sof Drinks",
                        "label": "Juices & sof Drinks"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "code": "B320",
                "cartType": "halfCart",
                "typesOfItems": [
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                        "value": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                        "label": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "box7"
            }
        ],
        "index": "Galley1",
        "imageGalley": "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png"
    },
    {
        "code": "756WP",
        "id": "full",
        "name": "Full Cart",
        "boxId": "box4",
        "cartQuantityAllots": [
            {
                "code": "89SDA",
                "cartType": "smu",
                "typesOfItems": [
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Plastic Glasses",
                        "value": "Plastic Glasses",
                        "label": "Plastic Glasses"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "index": "Galley1",
        "imageGalley": "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png"
    }
]
```

the updated object is

```
const upDt={
    "trolleyId": "A2004",
    "cartItems": [
        {
            "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
            "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
            "value": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
            "label": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine"
        },
        {
            "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
            "name": "SMU-Tea",
            "value": "SMU-Tea",
            "label": "SMU-Tea"
        }
    ],
    "cartType": "fullCart",
    "fullCart": 2,
    "halfCart": 1,
    "smu": 2,
    "stowage": 2,
    "index": "Galley1"
}
```

also for finding the object inside the main array arr i have another object to compare which has a property id

```
const edtA={
    "code": "B320",
    "cartType": "halfCart",
    "typesOfItems": [
        {
            "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
            "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
            "value": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
            "label": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine"
        }
    ],
    "id": "box7"
}
```

what i have tried

```
const res=arr.map(a=>{if(a.boxId===edtA.id){
return a.cartQuantityAllots.map(ct=>{if(ct.code===edtA.code){
return {code:upDt.trolleyId,cartType:upDt.cartType,typesOfItems:upDt.cartItems}
}
return ct})
}
return a})

console.log(res)
```

this works for the scenario but in my project  i am getting a unexpected array with an object inside this.Why is it giving different result.
my expected result is,

```
const res=[{
  boxId: "box6",
  cartQuantityAllots: [{
  cartType: "halfCart",
  code: "A2001",
  typesOfItems: [{
  key: "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
  label: "Crockery - Tea Coffee Cups",
  name: "Crockery - Tea Coffee Cups",
  value: "Crockery - Tea Coffee Cups"
}, {
  key: "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
  label: "SMU-Tea",
  name: "SMU-Tea",
  value: "SMU-Tea"
}, {
  key: "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
  label: "All purpose glass",
  name: "All purpose glass",
  value: "All purpose glass"
}]
}],
  code: "756WP",
  id: "full",
  imageGalley: "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png",
  index: "Galley1",
  name: "Full Cart"
}, [{
  cartType: "halfCart",
  code: "A2002",
  typesOfItems: [{
  key: "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
  label: "Beverages - Juice &amp; Softdrinks",
  name: "Beverages - Juice &amp; Softdrinks",
  value: "Beverages - Juice &amp; Softdrinks"
}, {
  key: "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
  label: "Juices &amp; sof Drinks",
  name: "Juices &amp; sof Drinks",
  value: "Juices &amp; sof Drinks"
}]
}, {
  cartType: "fullCart",
  code: "A2004",
  typesOfItems: [{
  key: "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
  label: "Bar Cart - Beer &amp; Wine",
  name: "Bar Cart - Beer &amp; Wine",
  value: "Bar Cart - Beer &amp; Wine"
}, {
  key: "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
  label: "SMU-Tea",
  name: "SMU-Tea",
  value: "SMU-Tea"
}]
}], {
  boxId: "box4",
  cartQuantityAllots: [{
  cartType: "smu",
  code: "89SDA",
  typesOfItems: [{
  key: "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
  label: "Plastic Glasses",
  name: "Plastic Glasses",
  value: "Plastic Glasses"
}]
}],
  code: "756WP",
  id: "full",
  imageGalley: "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png",
  index: "Galley1",
  name: "Full Cart"
}]
```

Comment: Post your code as a [mcve], 
⏩[look for the brackets `<>` button](https://i.ibb.co/935zWhk/mcve.jpg)⏪